# SQL maxdate for each given year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Searched through the posts found similar questions but was not able to translate answer(s) to solve for the issue I'm having.  The output of this selection should be account_id,  most recent wip_stmt_date in each calendar year with aggreated financials, some of which which I excluded from the data output below.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

---

```
SELECT a.account_id,
   a.wip_stmt_date,
   SUM(b."Cost to Complete") AS "Cost to Complete",
   SUM(b."Estimated Gross Profit") AS "Estimated Gross Profit",
   SUM(b."Earned Gross Profit") AS "Earned Gross Profit"

FROM WIP a
   inner join (
SELECT wip_id,
    SUM(wip_compl_cost) AS "Cost to Complete",
    SUM(est_gross_profit) AS "Estimated Gross Profit",
    SUM(earned_gross_profit) AS "Earned Gross Profit"
        FROM WIP_Detail GROUP BY wip_id
         ) b

 ON a.wip_id = b.wip_id

 WHERE year(a.wip_stmt_date) > 2008 and account_id is not null

 GROUP BY a.account_id, a.wip_stmt_date
```

---

```
 account_id      wip_stmt_date        Cost to Complete
    400      1996-06-30 00:00:00.000     989704310 don't need
    400      1996-09-30 00:00:00.000    1168271446 don't need
    400      1996-12-31 00:00:00.000    1200403025
    400      1997-03-31 00:00:00.000    1232629057 don't need
    400      1997-06-30 00:00:00.000    1114344673 don't need
    400      1997-09-30 00:00:00.000    1304671991 don't need
    400      1997-12-31 00:00:00.000    1407410337
    400      1998-03-31 00:00:00.000    1549329678 don't need
    400      1998-09-30 00:00:00.000    1608083965
    400      1999-03-31 00:00:00.000    1663183272
    400      2000-03-31 00:00:00.000    1673019904
    400      2001-03-31 00:00:00.000    1828818751
    400      2002-09-30 00:00:00.000    2847506038 don't need
    400      2002-12-31 00:00:00.000    3366648755
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Also tag your question with DBMS.

Comment: What is the difference between WIP and WIP_Detail table? Why in your where clause you are excluding everything less than 2008 even though in your table you show you need data for 1996/97?

Comment: I don't need data prior to 2009, this is sample data before I added the where clause date filter, Wip table contains different financial values (which I don't need) and the date stamp (wip_stmt_date) for when a wip is received, you could receive up to 12 wips per year each one provinding updated financial data, only the last one is important

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL Server answer. Syntax changes may be needed for other DBMS.

```
SELECT account_id, 
MAX(wip_stmt_date), 
SUM("Cost to Complete") AS "Cost to Complete", 
SUM("Estimate Gross Profit") AS "Estimated Gross Profit", 
SUM("Earned Gross Profit) AS "Earned Gross Profit"
FROM wip_id a (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN WIP b
ON a.wip_id = b.WIP
WHERE account_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, wip_stmt_date), account_id
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is this straight forward, wip_stmt_date is in table WIP, financial values are in the WIP_Detail table, wip_id is common, I created the sub select is to aggregate the financials given by wip_id